# Mutual SSL Authentication - Local certificate in sslstream returning 'null' instead of certificate on client

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, sslstream

I am working on creating an windows service which will make a call to a API.  For this process, I am trying to establish a Mutual (Two way) SSL authentication.  Since I am newbie to this.  I tried to implement a simple client and server project which will authenticate mutually.

I have created the self signed certificate exchanged and added in trusted certificates.

**My Client**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;


namespace MutualSslDemo.Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //  hostName
            var hostName    = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostName"];
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(hostName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("hostName", "Please specify a valid hostname to connect to.");

            //  port
            var port        = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"]);
            if (port <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Please specify a valid port number.");

            //  certificate and password
            var certificate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificate"];
            var password    = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
            var certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection(new X509Certificate2(certificate, password));

            RunClient(hostName, port, certificates);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None);
        }


        static bool CertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
          if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Validation Error");
            Console.WriteLine(sslPolicyErrors.ToString());
            return false;
          }
          else
            return true;
        }

        static void RunClient(string hostName, int port, X509Certificate2Collection certificates)
        {
            // Create a TCP/IP client socket.
            // machineName is the host running the server application.
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostName, port);
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");
            // Create an SSL stream that will close the client's stream.
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
                client.GetStream(),
                false,
                new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidationCallback));

            // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
            try
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostName, certificates, SslProtocols.Default, true);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                DisplaySecurityLevel(sslStream);
                DisplaySecurityServices(sslStream);
                DisplayCertificateInformation(sslStream);
                DisplayStreamProperties(sslStream);
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
                if (e.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
                client.Close();
                return;
            }
            // Encode a test message into a byte array.
            // Signal the end of the message using the "<EOF>".
            byte[] messsage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello from the client.<EOF>");
            // Send hello message to the server. 
            sslStream.Write(messsage);
            sslStream.Flush();
            // Read message from the server.
            string serverMessage = ReadMessage(sslStream);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", serverMessage);
            Console.ResetColor();
            // Close the client connection.
            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Client closed.");
        }

        static string ReadMessage(SslStream sslStream)
        {
            // Read the  message sent by the server.
            // The end of the message is signaled using the
            // "<EOF>" marker.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
            int bytes = -1;
            do
            {
                 bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to UTF8
                // in case a character spans two buffers.
                Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
                decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
                messageData.Append(chars);
                // Check for EOF.
                if (messageData.ToString().IndexOf("<EOF>") != -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            } while (bytes != 0);

            return messageData.ToString();
        }

        static void DisplaySecurityLevel(SslStream stream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cipher: {0} strength {1}", stream.CipherAlgorithm, stream.CipherStrength);
            Console.WriteLine("Hash: {0} strength {1}", stream.HashAlgorithm, stream.HashStrength);
            Console.WriteLine("Key exchange: {0} strength {1}", stream.KeyExchangeAlgorithm, stream.KeyExchangeStrength);
            Console.WriteLine("Protocol: {0}", stream.SslProtocol);
        }

        static void DisplaySecurityServices(SslStream stream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Is authenticated: {0} as server? {1}", stream.IsAuthenticated, stream.IsServer);
            Console.WriteLine("IsSigned: {0}", stream.IsSigned);
            Console.WriteLine("Is Encrypted: {0}", stream.IsEncrypted);
        }

        static void DisplayStreamProperties(SslStream stream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Can read: {0}, write {1}", stream.CanRead, stream.CanWrite);
            Console.WriteLine("Can timeout: {0}", stream.CanTimeout);
        }

        static void DisplayCertificateInformation(SslStream stream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Certificate revocation list checked: {0}", stream.CheckCertRevocationStatus);

            X509Certificate localCertificate = stream.LocalCertificate;
            if (stream.LocalCertificate != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Local cert was issued to {0} and is valid from {1} until {2}.",
                    localCertificate.Subject,
                    localCertificate.GetEffectiveDateString(),
                    localCertificate.GetExpirationDateString());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Local certificate is null.");
            }
            // Display the properties of the client's certificate.
            X509Certificate remoteCertificate = stream.RemoteCertificate;
            if (remoteCertificate != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Remote cert was issued to {0} and is valid from {1} until {2}.",
                    remoteCertificate.Subject,
                    remoteCertificate.GetEffectiveDateString(),
                    remoteCertificate.GetExpirationDateString());
                Console.WriteLine(remoteCertificate);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Remote certificate is null.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My Server**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;


namespace MutualSslDemo.Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //  port
            var port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"]);
            if (port <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Please specify a valid port number.");

            //  certificate and password
            var fileName    = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificate"];
            var password    = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(fileName, password);

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(OnRemoteCertificateValidationCallback);
            SslTcpServer.RunServer(port, certificate);
        }

        static bool OnRemoteCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None);
        }

        public sealed class SslTcpServer
        {
            // The certificate parameter specifies the name of the file 
            // containing the machine certificate.
            public static void RunServer(int serverPort, X509Certificate2 certificate)
            {
                // Create a TCP/IP (IPv4) socket and listen for incoming connections.
                var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, serverPort);
                listener.Start();


                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client to connect...");
                    // Application blocks while waiting for an incoming connection.
                    // Type CNTL-C to terminate the server.
                    var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    ProcessClient(client, certificate);
                }
            }

            static void ProcessClient(TcpClient client, X509Certificate certificate)
            {
                // A client has connected. Create the 
                // SslStream using the client's network stream.
                var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);

                try
                {
                    // Authenticate the server and requires the client to authenticate.
                    sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate, true, SslProtocols.Default, true);
                    // Display the properties and settings for the authenticated stream.
                    DisplaySecurityLevel(sslStream);
                    DisplaySecurityServices(sslStream);
                    DisplayCertificateInformation(sslStream);
                    DisplayStreamProperties(sslStream);

                    // Set timeouts for the read and write to 5 seconds.
                    sslStream.ReadTimeout = 5000;
                    sslStream.WriteTimeout = 5000;
                    // Read a message from the client.   
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client message...");
                    string messageData = ReadMessage(sslStream);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", messageData);
                    Console.ResetColor();

                    // Write a message to the client.
                    byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello from the server.<EOF>");
                    Console.WriteLine("Sending hello message.");
                    sslStream.Write(message);
                }
                catch (AuthenticationException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
                    if (e.InnerException != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
                    sslStream.Close();
                    client.Close();
                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    // The client stream will be closed with the sslStream
                    // because we specified this behavior when creating
                    // the sslStream.
                    sslStream.Close();
                    client.Close();
                }
            }

            static string ReadMessage(SslStream sslStream)
            {
                // Read the  message sent by the client.
                // The client signals the end of the message using the
                // "<EOF>" marker.
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = -1;
                do
                {
                    // Read the client's test message.
                    bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to UTF8
                    // in case a character spans two buffers.
                    Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                    char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
                    decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
                    messageData.Append(chars);
                    // Check for EOF or an empty message.
                    if (messageData.ToString().IndexOf("<EOF>") != -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                } while (bytes != 0);

                return messageData.ToString();
            }

            static void DisplaySecurityLevel(SslStream stream)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cipher: {0} strength {1}", stream.CipherAlgorithm, stream.CipherStrength);
                Console.WriteLine("Hash: {0} strength {1}", stream.HashAlgorithm, stream.HashStrength);
                Console.WriteLine("Key exchange: {0} strength {1}", stream.KeyExchangeAlgorithm, stream.KeyExchangeStrength);
                Console.WriteLine("Protocol: {0}", stream.SslProtocol);
            }

            static void DisplaySecurityServices(SslStream stream)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Is authenticated: {0} as server? {1}", stream.IsAuthenticated, stream.IsServer);
                Console.WriteLine("IsSigned: {0}", stream.IsSigned);
                Console.WriteLine("Is Encrypted: {0}", stream.IsEncrypted);
            }

            static void DisplayStreamProperties(SslStream stream)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can read: {0}, write {1}", stream.CanRead, stream.CanWrite);
                Console.WriteLine("Can timeout: {0}", stream.CanTimeout);
            }

            static void DisplayCertificateInformation(SslStream stream)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Certificate revocation list checked: {0}", stream.CheckCertRevocationStatus);

                X509Certificate localCertificate = stream.LocalCertificate;
                if (stream.LocalCertificate != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Local cert was issued to {0} and is valid from {1} until {2}.",
                        localCertificate.Subject,
                        localCertificate.GetEffectiveDateString(),
                        localCertificate.GetExpirationDateString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Local certificate is null.");
                }
                // Display the properties of the client's certificate.
                X509Certificate remoteCertificate = stream.RemoteCertificate;
                if (remoteCertificate != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Remote cert was issued to {0} and is valid from {1} until {2}.",
                        remoteCertificate.Subject,
                        remoteCertificate.GetEffectiveDateString(),
                        remoteCertificate.GetExpirationDateString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Remote certificate is null.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this work if I run both server and client in locally(localhost).  However, when I tried this in two different machine (within a network LAN).  It throws an error of

```
Exception: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

in **My Server** code in this line.

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate, true, SslProtocols.Default, true);
```

In **My Client** I noticed that the `CertificateValidationCallback` return `true`

But I found `Local certificate is null` in `DisplayCertificateInformation`

Sorry, I am really new to both C# and security.  Can anyone please help me on this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, I am experiencing an issue like yours at the moment. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: @nozzleman still waiting ;(

Answer (score 0):

Certificate error

```
static bool CertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{          
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should elaborate more, I cannot understand why is this helpful.