# How to do Mutual Authentication in C#?

Tags: c#, mutual-authentication

I need to know how to do Mutual Authentication in c#. I know it is pretty easy in WCF applications. However, I have to do two way SSL authentication from console applciation in C#.  I have the two public certificates for client and  server.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 2 way authentication between a console app and what?

Comment: I am not sure about server side implementation.  They have just provided the host name and Port for me!

Comment: I have added the detailed question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063745/mutual-ssl-authentication-local-certificate-in-sslstream-returning-null-inst).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use the WCF libraries also in a console application. So you should be able to reuse your existing code.

If you really want do it without WCF, there are examples out there on how to use ssl Client certificates in C#: http://www.example-code.com/csharp/https_upload_with_cert.asp

Comment: Linked answers are discouraged.  There should have been an example/synopsis posted.  That link is now broken and so now helps no one.